# keras model equivalent of tf.depth_to_space

Tags: python, keras

I want to accomplish the equivalent of tf.depth_to_space in a Keras model.  Specifically, the data in the Keras model is shaped H x W x 4 (i.e., depth of 4) and I want to permute the data so that the output is sized H x W x 1, with the mapping done as viewing the 4 input channels as 2x2 blocks; i.e.,

input location is y, x, k

output location is 2*y+(k//2), 2*x+(k%2), 1

I know that I can get the correct shape with:

```py
outputs = keras.layers.Reshape((H*2,W*2,1), input_shape=(H,W,4))(inputs)
```

But I think that the mapping will be

input location is y, x, k

Linear_addess is y*W*4+x*4+k

output location is Linear_addess//(H*2), Linear_addess % (H*2), 1

which is not what I want

I tried directly using the

```py
outputs = tf.depth_to_space(inputs, 2)
```

but that lead to an error:
TypeError: Output tensors to a Model must be Keras tensors. Found Tensor("DepthToSpace:0", shape=(?, 1024, 1024, 1), dtype=float32)

the problem can be seen with this simple function

```py
def simple_net(H=512, W=512):

    inputs = keras.layers.Input((H, W, 4))

    # gets the correct shape but not the correct order
    outputs = keras.layers.Reshape((H*2,W*2,1), input_shape=(H,W,4))(inputs)

    # Run time error message
    #outputs = tf.depth_to_space(output_planes, 2)
    model = keras.models.Model(inputs, outputs)
    return model
```

Answer (score 6):

## you should use Keras Lamda layer

```
from keras.layers import Lambda
import tensorflow as tf

Subpixel_layer = Lambda(lambda x:tf.nn.depth_to_space(x,scale))
x = Subpixel_layer(inputs=x)
```

**MINIMAL MODEL**

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.layers import Input,Lambda

in=Input(shape=(32,32,3))
x = Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu')(in)
x = Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu')(x) 
sub_layer = Lambda(lambda x:tf.nn.depth_to_space(x,2))
x = sub_layer(inputs=x)
model = Model(inputs=in, outputs=x)
# model.compile(optimizer = Adam(), loss = mean_squared_error)
model.summary()
```

[Summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dq5tI.png)